# How can I redirect users to different pages with Link

Tags: reactjs

I have the code like bellow. I want when I click in the link it should direct me to the other page.
But It doesn't do anything. Could someone please help with this?

```
<Link className="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" to={`/blog/${this.props.post.slug}`}>
    <div className="portfolio-hover">
        <div className="portfolio-hover-content">
            <i className="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    {this.props.post.PostImage ? this.props.post.PostImage.length > 0 ? <img style={{width: '100%'}} className="img-fluid" src={API.makeFileURL(this.props.post.PostImage[0].thumbnail, null)} alt="/"/>
: null: null}      
</Link>
```

Comment: can you share route configuration of /blog/ route

Comment: Did you console this {this.props.post.slug} value?

Answer (score 0):

You may create separate component for navigation purpose where you may put all of your url links

NavBar component

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const NavBar = ({ menuData }) => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
          {menuData.map(menu => {
            return (
              <li>
                <Link to={menu.path}>
                  {menu.name}
                </Link>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
     </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

You have to ensure the route section, this section specially manage your route and it will redirect you to your desired page/component based on url change

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
   <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

So I keep the NavBar and the route closely in App.js

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./navbar";
import { Route, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    navBars: [
      { name: "Home", path: "/" },
      { name: "Login", path: "/login" }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <main>
          <NavBar
            menuData={this.state.navBars}
          ></NavBar>
          <div className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And finally you have to make sure your navbar/Link and Routes should be under Router, So BrowserRouter confirm this thing

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

You may have a look in my index.js

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Hope it will help you