# Navigation is not working in ReactJS web app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[image]I'm creating a web application using the ReactJS framework. I have added the bootstrap Navbar component as navigation of my website. But I'm not able to navigate through the pages using href attribute.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import Linux from './Linux'


function Navbar(){
    return(
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Learn to Code</a>
  <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li className="nav-item active">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href="">Development</a>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href="./Linux">Linux</a>
      </li>
```

I have tried using `react-router-dom`. How can I navigate to other pages in react application?

This is how I have added the react-router-dom Link method.

```
import Link from 'react-router-dom';

<li className="nav-item">
        <Link to='/Linux'></Link>
</li>
```

Then I was getting following error: Attempted import error: 'react-router-dom' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Link').

Comment: I have tried react-router-dom but it wasn't working

Comment: can you show what have you tried using `react-router-dom` also by using href `/Linux` do you mean to load new page on that url or are you intending to open component instead

Comment: I have added react-router-dom code

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it seems you need understand how to react router in first place, you can get that info from their website or following tutorials, it will save you bunch of time down the road on understanding proper usage.

Answer (score 1):

You may follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803074/how-can-i-redirect-users-to-different-pages-with-link/58803546#58803546), here I try to give a little more detail idea about  how navigation works and how to write code for that. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

`Attempted import error: 'react-router-dom' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Link')`

As this error tells you, `Link` is not the default export of 'react-router-dom'. You'll need to use object destructuring to be able to import it:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```